# Solving $\lim_{x\to 0}\bigg( \Big( \frac{1+\sin(x)\cos(\alpha x)}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)} \Big) ^{\cot^3(x)}\bigg)$: my mistake or a book typo?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\bigg( \Big( \frac{1+\sin(x)\cos(\alpha x)}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)} \Big) ^{\cot^3(x)}\bigg)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}  \bigg( \Big( \frac{1+\sin(x)\cos(\alpha x)+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)-\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)} \Big) ^{\cot^3(x)}\bigg)$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0}  \bigg( \Big( 1+\frac{\sin(x)\cos(\alpha x)-\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}\Big)^{\cot^3(x) \cdot \frac{1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}{\sin(x)\cos(\alpha x)-\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)} \cdot \frac{\sin(x)\cos(\alpha x)-\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}{1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x)}} \bigg) $$

$$e^{\lim_{x\to 0} \big( \frac{\cos^3(x)\sin(x)(\cos(\alpha x) - \cos(\beta x))}{\sin(x)\sin^2(x) (1+\sin(x)\cos(\beta x))} \big)}$$

Currently disregarding the exponent, because the font is small.

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \big( \frac{\cos(\alpha x) - \cos(\beta x)}{\sin^2(x)} \big)$$

Through Taylor's expansion,

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \big( \frac{1-\frac{\alpha^2x^2}{2} -1 + \frac{\beta^2x^2}{2}}{x^2} \big)$$

And the answer is

$$e^{\frac{\beta^2 - \alpha^2}{2}}.$$

The answer in the book, however, is $e^{\beta^2 - \alpha^2}$. The formula for the difference of two cosines also leaves me with $e^{\frac{\beta^2 - \alpha^2}{2}}$, and I feel like there's a typo, but maybe I went wrong somewhere?

Comment: Your book has a typo.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks! Do you suggest I delete this post, answer to myself and accept my own answer, or wait for another user to post the answer so I could accept it? I don't want my question hanging adding to the pile of unanswered ones.

Comment: Answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo, as affirmed in the comments.